# Find the lowest value of $x$ so that $x \in (A \setminus B)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets for which the following applies:

$A = \{x: \text{GCD(}x,12) = 1\}$
$B = \{x: x\ \text{is a prime}\}$

Find the lowest value of $x$ so that $x \in (A \setminus B)$.

$x \in A \setminus B$ means that $x \in A$  and $x \notin B$. So, $x$ is not a prime, and its greatest common divisor with 12 is 1...

How to solve?

Comment: The set $A$ contains all numbers which have no commod divisor to $12=2\cdot 2\cdot 3$... thus...

Comment: If $1$ is among the considered $x$, it's evidently the smallest element of $A\setminus B$. If $1$ is excluded, what does $\gcd(x,12) = 1$ tell you about the prime factorisation of $x$?

Comment: But isn't 1 a prime?

Comment: $\operatorname{GCD}(x,12)=1$ means that $x$ is not a multiple of $2$ nor $3$. What is the smallest non-prime which you can form using only primes greater than $3$?

Comment: Is $5^2 = 25$ correct?

Comment: $1$ is not a prime by definition. And yes. $25$ looks fine. See Daniel's answer.

Comment: Oh, then 1 is the answer?

Comment: Actually, $-1001$ is relatively prime to 12, and is not a prime, and is lower than 25 (and also lower than 1), so it's a better answer than either of those. Of course, $-10000001$ is an even better answer, and $-100000000001$ is better still.

Comment: I should have stated that $x \in Z^+$, so 1 is the correct answer?

Comment: If $x$ is to be a positive integer, then it can't get any smaller than 1, and, since 1 is prime to 12 and is not prime, it must be the answer. My guess is that it's not the answer intended by the person who set the problem. I bet that person had 25 in mind as the answer. But the way you have posed the question, it has to be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Answer the literal question of "How to solve?" rather than "What is the answer?", I'd expect something like the following approach:

1. Find the first few members of each set, eg:

$$A = \{1,5,7,11,13,17,...\} \\
B = \{2,3,5,7,11,13,...\} $$

2. Clearly $1$ is the solution, but assuming for a moment that the question had forbidden it, we can think about the structure of the sets...

   - Set $A$ has a simple construction pattern ($12k+\{1,5,7,11\}$) but set $B$ we expect not to have a simple pattern from foreknowledge of primes
   - So why are we getting numbers in common?
3. Ideally here we'd see that the alternative view of $A$ is that it consists of all numbers coprime to both 2 and 3 - that is, it excludes only multiples of $2$ and $3$, and then link this to our knowledge of sieve methods for finding primes, which exclude multiples of **all** earlier members of the set of primes.
4. This gives us a characterization of $(A \setminus B)$: it is $\{1\}$ along with all composites with smallest prime factor  $\ge 5$. And the second smallest member of that set is of course $25$ as already discussed.